# How to capture the current math style?

Tags: math-mode

`\mathchoice` helps to distinguish between math styles:

```
\mathchoice
  {<something in \displaystyle>}
  {<something in \textstyle>}
  {<something in \scriptstyle>}
  {<something in \scriptscriptstyle>}
```

How would one use `\mathchoice` to capture the current math style? The following does not work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getmathstyle}{%
  \mathchoice
    {\global\def\curmathstyle{\displaystyle}}
    {\global\def\curmathstyle{\textstyle}}
    {\global\def\curmathstyle{\scriptstyle}}
    {\global\def\curmathstyle{\scriptscriptstyle}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
$\getmathstyle$ \meaning\curmathstyle\par
$\displaystyle\getmathstyle$ \meaning\curmathstyle\par
$\scriptstyle\getmathstyle$ \meaning\curmathstyle\par
$\scriptscriptstyle\getmathstyle$ \meaning\curmathstyle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related? [Is there a test for the different styles inside maths mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1223)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: The linked question is definitely related, but I feel it doesn't address the question. It seems like the original question was later adapted to incorporate the mysteries of `\mathchoice`, but not to capture the current math style for possible later use.

Comment: Now _this_ is a question deserving the [LaTeX] tag. In TeX, the answer would be "No way!!"

Comment: Related Question: [Proper use of \mathchoice](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43978/proper-use-of-mathchoice).

Comment: It's all the fault of `\over` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42855/whats-behind-over/42856#42856

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I probably should have posted this answer ([Proper use of \mathchoice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43978/proper-use-of-mathchoice/114594#114594)) here, but I will just refer you to it.  It got adapted into the `scalerel` package, where I introduce the syntax

```
\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}
```

which can also be nested as

```
\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}...}
```

The invocation of `\ThisStyle` saves the current math style, which can later be recalled via `\SavedStyle`.  A final noteworthy point is that this approach uses the TeX primitive `\mathchoice`, which will not suffer the many compatibility issues that others have noted with the `mathstyle` package.

---

Werner asks for an MWE here, so here is one, in which a math notation is introduced (a triple-stacked subscript) that works just fine in `\textstyle`.  But, as originally defined, changes in the math style cannot migrate into the stack, because it is formed inside a LaTeX box construct.  Thus, to carry the mathstyle into the stack, the above-described syntax from the `scalerel` package is introduced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\stackMath\setstackgap{S}{1pt}
\parindent 0in\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
A unique symbol in textstyle math\\
$A_{\Shortunderstack{a \\ b \\ c}}$

However, the stack doesn't see the scriptstyle\\
$\scriptstyle A_{\Shortunderstack{a \\ b \\ c}}$

Now it does:\\
\def\subterm{\ThisStyle{ A_{\Shortunderstack{%
  \SavedStyle a \\ \SavedStyle b \\ \SavedStyle c}}}}
$\textstyle\subterm$
$\scriptstyle\subterm$
$\scriptscriptstyle\subterm$

In these cases, the subscript is one reduced from\\ the main text:\\
\def\subterm{A_{\ThisStyle{\Shortunderstack{%
  \SavedStyle a \\ \SavedStyle b \\ \SavedStyle c}}}}
$\textstyle\subterm$
$\scriptstyle\subterm$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The actual construction of these macros in `scalerel.sty` is straightforward.  It uses `\mathchoice` to define a switch at the invocation of `\ThisStyle` called `\m@switch`, defined as one of four unique letters, depending on the current math style.  Then it proceeds with the argument of `\ThisStyle` within the `\mathchoice`.  Upon coming across a `\SavedStyle` within that argument, it uses the `\m@switch` character to construct a macro name, by adding the switch character to the end of the string `\@mstyle`.  Those four variants `\@mstyleD`, `\@mstyleT`, `\@mstyleS`, and `\@mstyles` just regurgitate the math style which had been saved at the invocation of `\ThisStyle`.

```
\def\@mstyleD{\displaystyle}
\def\@mstyleT{\textstyle}
\def\@mstyleS{\scriptstyle}
\def\@mstyles{\scriptscriptstyle}
%
\def\SavedStyle{\csname @mstyle\m@switch\endcsname}
%
\newcommand\ThisStyle[1]{%
  \ifmmode%
    \def\@mmode{T}\mathchoice%
      {\edef\m@switch{D}#1}%
      {\edef\m@switch{T}#1}%
      {\edef\m@switch{S}#1}%
      {\edef\m@switch{s}#1}%
  \else%
    \def\@mmode{F}%
    \edef\m@switch{T}#1%
  \fi%
}
```

Comment: Have you considered the impact of grouping on the spacing in math mode? It doesn't really affect the solution though. For completeness, could you add your definition of `\MS` and `\SavedMathStyle` here in a minimal example?

Comment: @Werner to this point, I have not found a case where grouping adversely affects the spacing.  Obviously, the argument of `\ThisStyle` needs to encompass enough of what follows to avoid that pitfall.  But there always seems to be a logical place to end the argument, which doesn't affect spacing.

Answer (score 15):

The [`mathstyle` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathstyle) provides a means to tap into the current math style and redefines `\mathchoice` as a switch. As such, the following is a possible solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathstyle}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathstyle
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getmathstyle}{
  \global\edef\curmathstyle{\expandafter\@gobble\mathchoice{\@@displaystyle}{\@@textstyle}{\@@scriptstyle}{\@@scriptscriptstyle}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\verb|\textstyle|: $xyz\getmathstyle$ \meaning\curmathstyle \par
\verb|\displaystyle|: $\displaystyle xyz\getmathstyle$ \meaning\curmathstyle \par
\verb|\scriptstyle|: $\scriptstyle xyz\getmathstyle$ \meaning\curmathstyle \par
\verb|\scriptscriptstyle|: $\scriptscriptstyle xyz\getmathstyle$ \meaning\curmathstyle
\end{document}
```

`\mathpalette` acts like a server for `\mathchoice` (see [The mysteries of `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/5764)) and can be used to extract the math style in a slightly more elegant way:

[image]

```
%...
\usepackage{mathstyle}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathstyle
\newcommand{\getmathstyle}{%
  \mathpalette{\global\let\curmathstyle}{\relax}%
}
%...
```

Comment: mathstyle package has some interesting (but not good) interactions with amsmath (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114467/nonfatal-but-symptomatic-conflict-of-amsmath-and-mathstyle-packages)

Answer (score 13):

LuaTeX provides a `\mathstyle` primitive which takes the following values for different math styles:

- 0 = display
- 1 = crampeddisplay
- 2 = text
- 3 = crampedtext
- 4 = script
- 5 = crampedscript
- 6 = scriptscript
- 7 = crampedscriptscript

Here is an example usage:

```
\starttext
\startlines
$\displaystyle                  \sum_{k=0}^n (a_k + b_k): \mathstyle$
$\crampeddisplaystyle           \sum_{k=0}^n (a_k + b_k): \mathstyle$
$\textstyle                     \sum_{k=0}^n (a_k + b_k): \mathstyle$
$\crampedtextstyle              \sum_{k=0}^n (a_k + b_k): \mathstyle$
$\scriptstyle                   \sum_{k=0}^n (a_k + b_k): \mathstyle$
$\crampedscriptstyle            \sum_{k=0}^n (a_k + b_k): \mathstyle$
$\scriptscriptstyle             \sum_{k=0}^n (a_k + b_k): \mathstyle$
$\crampedscriptscriptstyle      \sum_{k=0}^n (a_k + b_k): \mathstyle$
\stoplines
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

You can do something based on the current mathstyle by using

```
\ifcase\mathstyle 
 ...
 \or
 ...
 \or
 ... % etc.
\fi
```

An interesting usage is

```
$\mathstyle_{\mathstyle_{\mathstyle}}$
```

which gives [image] showing that cramped style is active in subscripts and subsubscripts.

Comment: But this fails for the same reason that `\mathchoice` is in TeX at all, the use of `\over` retrospectively changes the style of the first part of a group. If you go `$$ \sum_0 \mathstyle {\sum_0  \mathstyle \over \sum_0 \mathstyle} $$  \bye` then the second sum is in textstyle because it is in the fraction, but mathstyle gives  0 for the numerator as it hasn't see `\over` yet.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: LuaTeX has an `\Ustack` command to get around this (usage: `$\Ustack {a \over b}$`)

Comment: Yes or if you always use latex/amsmath commands with prefix forms and normal arguments like `\frac` rather than `\over` then the `mathchoice` package can keep track, as in the other answer, but if you allow the use of `\over` the primitive `\mathchoice` is the only option.

Comment: Does the mathstyle package also keep track of cramped style? I thought that there was no way to do that in pdftex.

Comment: Hi, could you please take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371134/4918. It about capturing the styl of a (de)nominator of a `\frac` … where this simple approach seems to fail.