# Aligning equality sign with overset text

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath, align

I'm typing a logic definition within an align environment that uses `\overset{def}{=}` from the `amsmath` environment.

However, the new sign is aligned vertically based on the equality sign, and not on the entire sign. In other words, the word `def` is not considered in the alignment, which produces a result that I don't like.

How can I correctly vertically align the sign?

An MWE (the spacing around the sign is not an issue):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
The definition of the satisfaction relation $M,s,g \models \phi$, which specifies that formula $\phi$ is true under valuation $g$ in state $s$ of model $M$, is given below.
\begin{align*}
M,s,g &\models x &\overset{def}{=} \qquad &s = g(x)\\
M,s,g &\models n &\overset{def}{=} \qquad &V(n) = {s}\\
M,s,g &\models p &\overset{def}{=} \qquad &s \ \epsilon \ V(p)\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Illustrative picture:

[image]

The equality signs are aligned vertically as per the red line.
However, the center of the new equality sign (`\overset{def}{=}`) is at the green line.
The new sign should move down until the green line overlaps with the red line (approximately anyway). Then the vertical alignment would be correct.

Comment: Added a picture to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I see no reason why the symbol should be moved down; on the other hand, I know that some supervisors have bizarre ideas about typography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you put the def/equal sign in a column of its own:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}}

\begin{document}
The definition of the satisfaction relation \( M,s,g \models \phi \), which specifies that formula \( \phi \) is true under valuation \( g \) in state \( s \) of model \( M \), is given below.
\begin{align*}
M,s,g &\models x &\defeq&&s &= g(x)\\
M,s,g &\models n &\defeq&&s&= V(n)\\
M,s,g &\models p &\defeq&&s &\in V(p)\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Additional changes made

- defined a command `\defeq` which typesets the `def` part in roman font.
- added alignment of right-hand column added at `=`, line 2 swapped to `s=V(n)` for symmetry
- `\(...\)` used instead of `$...$`

If you really want the symbol to be vertically centered, then there is a standard TeX command `\vcenter` which centers material with respect to the axis of the formula (roughly the height of the center of `x`).  The argument to `\vcenter` is material in vertical mode, so you need to box up the contents.  The naive version of this is:

[image: Vertically centered sample]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\defeq}{\vcenter{\hbox{\( \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} \)}}}

\begin{document}

The definition of the satisfaction relation \( M,s,g \models \phi \), which specifies that formula \( \phi \) is true under valuation \( g \) in state \( s \) of model \( M \), is given below.
\begin{align*}
M,s,g &\models x &\defeq&&s &= g(x)\\
M,s,g &\models n &\defeq&&s&= V(n)\\
M,s,g &\models p &\defeq&&s &\in V(p)\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

You can add @daleif's smaller version of the font if you so wish, by putting `\scriptscriptstyle` before `\mathrm`.

A more sophisticated version of the command would be, as in [How to capture the current math style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78872/15925):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathstyle}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defeq}{\vcenter{\hbox{\( \m@th\currentmathstyle
  \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} \)}}}
\makeatother
```

which would resize in superscripts.

Comment: Good pointers, but this still doesn't align the sign?

Comment: @Mythio I don't think the symbol should be moved vertically, it will look odd to a lot of people, besides I'd recommend changing Andrews macro a little `\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{def}}{=}}` to make the `def` smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'll try some options and let my supervisor decide what to use.