# how to make my \defeq lower

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

My tex code is shown below.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{\text{\tiny def}}{=}}
\begin{document}
$P\defeq A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I intend to move the \defeq sign in red rectangle into the green one. Or, in other words, i want the \defeq sign being center aligned in LaTeX character box.
Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Can't you find your happiness at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35404/34551 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114758/34551 ? Have you tried for instance `\newcommand{\defeq}{\vcenter{\hbox{\( \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} \)}}}`?

Comment: @Clément - None of the answers to the two posting you provided links to appear to address the OP's objective to shift the entire def-eq block down by a certain amount. Using `\vcenter` will place the def-eq block a bit too low for the OP's taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some low level commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defeq}{\mathrel{\aban@defeq}}
\newcommand{\aban@defeq}{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip\check@mathfonts
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      \fontsize{\ssf@size}{\z@}\normalfont def\cr
      \noalign{\kern1\p@}
      $\m@th=$\cr
      \noalign{\kern-.5\fontdimen22\textfont2}
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A=B\defeq P
\]

\end{document}
```

The spacing between “def” and “=” is set to one point, adapt it to your liking. The “=” is lowered by half the height of the math axis, which is available as `\fontdimen22\textfont2`.

[image]

Personally, I don't like such a symbol. If I were forced to use something like “it is defined to be”, I'd probably choose `\coloneq`, which is asymmetric. But I've never felt the mathematical need for such a symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that employs the LaTeX command `\raisebox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{\text{\tiny def}}{=}}
\newcommand{\ldefeq}{\mathrel{\raisebox{-0.3ex}{$\defeq$}}}
\begin{document}
$P\defeq A$, $P\ldefeq A$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The argument of `\lower` -- `0.3ex` in the code shown above -- may need to be adjusted slightly depending on the math font that's used by your document. `0.3ex` seems about right for Computer Modern (the math font shown in your screenshot) and Latin Modern; for the `newtxmath`, `newpxmath`, and `euler` math fonts, `0.29ex` is about right; for the `mtpro2` font package, `0.28ex` seems like the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. i wonder if there is a way to replace 0.3ex with a command?

Comment: `\raisebox` has been in LaTeX from day one.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this. For some reason, I had been under the mistaken impression that `\raisebox` was part of the `graphicx` package. I will update the code to use the "native" LaTeX command.