# Define macro inside \mathchoice

Tags: math-mode, macros

When I'm in mathmode, I want to get whether I'm using `displaystyle` or `textstyle` and save it to a macro `\mystyle`

To do so, I use `\mathchoice` and define `\mystyle` accordingly as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\def\mycommand#1{\mathchoice%
    {\global\let\mystyle\displaystyle}
    {\global\let\mystyle\textstyle}
    {\global\let\mystyle\textstyle}
    {\global\let\mystyle\textstyle}
    \mystyle#1}
\[\mycommand{\frac12}\]
\end{document}
```

*(Of course, I can just write `\mathchoice{\displaystyle #1}{\textstyle #1}...`, but I would like to save the current style and use it repeatedly)*

However, it seems that all `\global\let ...` sequences are executed and hence, the result is `\textstyle \frac12`.

What is the problem and how can I handle that?

Comment: you can not handle it, or know at the macro layer which style is used. `\mathchoice` is like `\hbox{..}\hbox{..}\hbox{..}\hbox{..}` which of the four boxes is used is decided after the math expression is finished and it is being converted into a horizontal box to add to the page.

Comment: Indeed, knowing the current style at the time of macro expansion is impossible because a subsequent `\over` that hasn't been seen yet (and may result from macro expansion, thus be hidden) could change “it”. That being said, maybe the OP would like to [read on `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/73317)...

Comment: The `scalerel` package, https://ctan.org/pkg/scalerel, has a `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...\SavedStyle...}` macro that remembers the current math style when invoked and can recall it repeatedly via `\SavedStyle`, but here is the key: `\SavedStyle` is only remembered within the context of the `\ThisStyle` argument...it cannot remember it indefinitely, for the reasons David noted.  Here is an example of how it works: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78872/how-to-capture-the-current-math-style/114658#114658

Comment: impossible up to LuaTeX's `\Ustack`. Anyway, it is definitely duplicate of the linked question, read that one carefully and understand the answer